# Using convolution integral with discontinuous (piecewise) functions

Tags: probability, convolution

$X,Y$ - uniform random variables, but here's a trick. While $f_Y(y)=1$ on $[0,1]$, $f_X(x)=5$ if $0<x<0.1, 0.9<x<1$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise.

I know how find $PDF_{X+Y}$ for continuous $f_X$, but what should I do here? Do I have to write two convolution integrals for $0<x<0.1, 0.9<x<1$? I assume that if $x\in(0.2,0.8)$ the integral will be $0$.

Comment: As you said you know how to apply the convolution: $\displaystyle f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx$, and it is still applicable here. As usual, you just need to find out the range that the integrand is non-zero first, i.e. the range of $x$ such that both $f_Y(z-x)$ and $f_X(x)$ are non-zero. Then do the calculation and simplify it.

Comment: For a start, that should be $f_X(x) = 5\cdot\Big[ 0<x<0.1 \text{ or } 0.9<x<1\Big]$ so, yes the density is zero between the two segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\displaystyle f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)f_X(z-y)dy = \int_{0}^{1} f_X(z-y)dy = \int_{z-1}^{z} f_X(x)dx.$